# What should I do after converting image to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am doing a project in which I have image of electricity meter reading. I need to extract the digits in the image.

I converted the image to a numpy array using the PIL Image function.

This is the code I typed

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img_data = Image.open('meter1.jpg' )
img_arr = np.array(img_data) 
print(img_arr)
```

I got this numpy array as the output

```
[[[  2  96  10]
  [  2  96  10]
  [  2  96  10]
  ...
  [ 18 144  47]
  [ 13 141  48]
  [ 10 139  46]]

 [[ 11 105  19]
  [ 10 106  19]
  [ 10 104  18]
  ...
  [ 28 156  59]
  [ 26 156  60]
  [ 24 155  59]]

 [[ 19 115  26]
  [ 16 115  25]
  [ 17 113  24]
  ...
  [ 30 162  60]
  [ 28 164  62]
  [ 26 165  64]]

  ...

 [[  0 126  18]
  [  0 126  18]
  [  0 126  18]
  ...
  [  4 211  77]
  [  4 211  79]
  [  6 213  83]]

 [[  0 126  18]
  [  0 126  18]
  ...
  [  4 212  76]
  [  4 211  79]
  [  6 213  83]]

 [[  1 124  17]
  [  1 124  17]
  [  1 124  17]
  ...
  [  5 211  76]
  [  5 210  79]
  [  7 212  81]]]
```

How do I use this numpy array to extract the numerical values or the digits or the numbers from this image?

[image]

It is a  seven segment display. Was is useful to convert the image to numpy array? Is there any other approach to do this. I have not done much of hand-on python so please help

Comment: Could you please add a plain python tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting digits from image with python and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663227/extracting-digits-from-image-with-python-and-opencv)

Comment: The code from "Extracting digits from image with python and OpenCV" does not seem to work on my image

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape' . I am getting this error please help

Answer (score 0):

it's better first to try doing some coding, because this way your coding skills improve. by the way, I wrote a script that save your digits into separate image files. hope it helps you in your project and improving your skills.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
directory,filename = os.path.split(__file__)
#x = np.array([ [ [255,0,0], [0,255,0], [0,0,255] ],[ [0,0,0],[128,128,128],[2,5,200] ] ],dtype=np.uint8)
main_img = Image.open('img.jpg')
x = np.array(main_img)
print(x)
#print(x[1][1] )# x[row number][column number]
#print(x.shape[1] )# x.shape = # of rows,# of cols
data_cols = []
bg_color = x[0][0]
start = False
start_id = -1
for j in range(0,x.shape[1]):
    for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
        if (x[i][j][0] < 5) and (x[i][j][2] < 10):
            if not start:
                start_id = j
                start = True
            break
        if i == x.shape[0]-1:
            start = False
            end_id = j
            if start_id>=0:
                data_cols.append([start_id,end_id])
                start_id=-1
print("Number of digits>",len(data_cols))
images = []
for i in range(0,len(data_cols)):
    images.append(x[:,data_cols[i][0]:data_cols[i][1]])
i = 0
for im_array in images:
    im = Image.fromarray(im_array,'RGB')
    im.save(directory + "\\" + str(i) + ".png")
    i += 1
```